# Show that the function sending $f$ to its derivative is continuos in compact-open topology.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{C}$ be an open subset of the complex plane.
We need to show that the function

$D$: $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$$\rightarrow$$\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$

$f \rightarrow f'$  is continous in the compact-open topology.

My try:

Since a basis of this topology is given by $B_f(K,\epsilon)$$=\{ g\in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ such  $|f-g|_K<\epsilon$ $\}$

I want to show that the inverse imagen $D^{-1}(B_{f'}(K,\epsilon))$ is open. Given  $g \in $ $D^{-1}$$(B_{f^{'}})$  I should find another ball $B_g \subset $$D^{-1}$$(B_{f^{'}})$

How can I construct this ball from knowing that $|g'-f'|<\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Have you thought about using the Cauchy Integral Formula, say, when $K$ is a closed disk?

Comment: I might look silly but i got stuck here:

$|\frac{1}{2\pi i} $$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)-g(z)}{(z-a)^2}|$$< \epsilon$

Comment: Well, what are you using for $\gamma$? How can you use a bound on $|f(z)-g(z)|$ on some set to get a bound on $|f'(a)-g'(a)|$ for $a\in K$?